# Synchronisation of pthreads using condition variables

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

The idea is to have multiple threads launch the same computation on different parts of the array. A computation is composed of several iterations (with a `while` loop). The threads must be synchronised together by the end of every iteration. The number of iterations that a given thread takes to perform a computation varies.

Here is what I have come up with so far, and I can't see what I am doing wrong:

```
pthread_cond_t continue_cond;
pthread_mutex_t waiting_threads_mut;
int num_waiting_threads = 0;


void WorkerProcess(void * args) {
    printf("Thread %d has started\n", args->thread_id);
    int to_process_indices = 1000;
    while (to_process_indices > 0) {

        to_process_indices -= (args->thread_id + 1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&waiting_threads_mut);
        ++num_waiting_threads;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&continue_cond);
        // num waiting threads % num threads == 0 => all threads are in computation, and have reached barrier, so continue
        // num waiting threads % num threads == 1 => 1 thread left in computation, so there is no need to wait, so continue
        // num waiting threads % num threads >1  => 2+ threads in computation, so they must continue syncing.
        while ((num_waiting_threads % args->num_threads) > 1) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&continue_cond, &waiting_threads_mut);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&waiting_threads_mut);
    }

    printf("Thread %d done with chunk..\n", args->thread_id);
}
```

Comment: We cannot run the code snippet because it is incomplete. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. If you are wondering what you might be doing wrong, you should show/describe the output/behavior you actually get and the expected output/behavior.

Comment: This comment look inaccurate: "num waiting threads % num threads == 1 => 1 thread left in computation".  Consider, for example, the very first thread to acquire the mutex.  It will increment `num_waiting_threads` to 1, then see that `num_waiting_threads % args->num_threads` is not greater than 1, so it will not wait.  The *last* thread to reach the synchronization point need not wait, but the first one to do so must (unless there is only one).

Comment: Note that you seem to be trying to hand-roll a barrier, but [pthreads already provides one](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_init).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I keep getting deadlocks. I've tried changing the position of the mutexes but I seriously do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But the thing is, a thread which has finished its work can exit the loop. Wouldn't the barrier then have to be dynamically resized? Or is there a simpler way around this

Comment: @snakelovah18119, there is a simpler way around it: threads that no longer have meaningful work to do can nevertheless return to the barrier without doing anything else.  This keeps the threads tied to the overall task, but that's a problem only if you have something else that you would rather they move on to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But wouldn't I be wasting clock cycles in doing this? Otherwise how can I alter my use of cond var's to actually make this functional?

Comment: Not particularly, @snakelovah18119.  Threads blocked at a barrier (or trying to acquire a mutex, or waiting on a CV) do not consume CPU.  And a thread's returning to the barrier immediately after passing through consumes negligible CPU.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249633/discussion-between-snakelovah18119-and-john-bollinger).